# How to check if an Object instance is a valid return for a Method

Tags: java, reflection

I have an Object instance `obj` and a Method object `method`. How can I check to see if `obj` would be a valid return for the `method`?

Assume `method` has no parameters and it's not a return type of `void` (confirmed as a getter).

For example, if `obj` is `null` then the return type for `method` cannot be a primitive. Alright, got that figured out. However, `Class.isAssignableFrom` does not take into account unboxing and boxing from primitives. For example `int.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)` returns false, but that would be a valid return for the method.

An option I could take is use `Class.cast` but using exceptions for programming flow is rather nasty and generating exceptions is also costly. But it is something I am aware of.

I'm kind of stumped on exactly how to figure this all out elegantly. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For primitive types, just maintain a mapping to their boxed types and verify against those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of cases you have to handle, isn’t that big. As you already mentioned, you must not return `null` if the return type is primitive. Then, you may consider unboxing, but don’t have to deal with boxing as you already have an object to return (as always in reflective operations).

So the only additional case you have to check is whether the return type is a primitive type and the object is of the appropriate wrapper type. If you want to keep the code concise you can settle on the fact that every wrapper type has a field named `TYPE` containing the `Class` object of the corresponding primitive type:

```
static boolean canReturn(Method m, Object value) {
    Class<?> rt=m.getReturnType();
    if(value==null) return !rt.isPrimitive();
    Class<?> act=value.getClass();
    if(rt==act) return true;
    if(rt.isPrimitive()) try {
        return act.getDeclaredField("TYPE").get(null)==rt;
    } catch(ReflectiveOperationException | NullPointerException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return rt.isAssignableFrom(act);
}
```

The code above takes some short-cuts. If the value is `null` we can immediately check the only constraint that the return type must not be a primitive type. Otherwise, we can safely assume that we have a non-`null` object and if its type happens to be an exact match of the return type, we short-cut the rest. If the return type is not a primitive type a simple `isAssignableFrom` will do. But if the return type is a primitive type, we optimistically try to read the field `TYPE`, assuming a wrapper type and compare. Any failure indicates that the actual type is not a wrapper type.

---

Of course, this Reflective check is concise but not the best coding style and doesn’t promise good performance. It’s only good for some ad-hoc checks. If you want to use that check more often and/or in production code, the best solution remains a manually filled map:

```
static final Map<Class<?>,Class<?>> PRIMITIVE2WRAPPER;
static {
    Map<Class<?>,Class<?>> p2w=new HashMap<>();
    p2w.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
    p2w.put(byte.class, Byte.class);
    p2w.put(short.class, Short.class);
    p2w.put(char.class, Character.class);
    p2w.put(int.class, Integer.class);
    p2w.put(long.class, Long.class);
    p2w.put(float.class, Float.class);
    p2w.put(double.class, Double.class);
    PRIMITIVE2WRAPPER=Collections.unmodifiableMap(p2w);
}
static boolean canReturn(Method m, Object value) {
    Class<?> rt=m.getReturnType();
    if(value==null) return !rt.isPrimitive();
    Class<?> act=value.getClass();
    if(rt==act) return true;
    return rt.isPrimitive()? PRIMITIVE2WRAPPER.get(rt)==act: rt.isAssignableFrom(act);
}
```

Comment: The second kind of solution was in my head, but I don't know why I considered it to not work. After a little testing it seems to function as expected. Thank you!

Comment: It took me some time too, to realize that neither boxing nor primitive widening conversions are an issue here (they aren’t supported by APIs like `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` anyway), so only the simplest unboxing conversion needs to be considered…

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't this work for you? - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)

This doesn't raise exceptions and does exactly what you expect.

Comment: Doesn't work if the Class is a primitive. For example for `int.class.isInstance(obj)` and you declare `obj` as `Object obj = 4` then it'll return false.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the operator `instanceof` in order to check whether the return object is an instance (or inherited from) your expected result type.

```
if (obj instanceof ExpectedResultClass) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: The return type is dynamic (hence the need for reflection).